# Получение данных из 1С на Python

Tags: python, 1с

Мне нужно при каждом создании чека на 1С получать его данные с помощью Python.

Comment: Можно сказать, что мне нужен способ постоянного парса данных из 1C при помощи Python

Comment: Добавьте в описание название конфигурации, так как на базе 1с создано огромное количество различных систем. Вам нужно в момент проведения чека(записи в БД) получать данные, или можно в конце дня по всем чекам за день?

Comment: В момент создания

Comment: тогда скорее всего потребуется доработка со стороны 1с, так как готового api скорее всего нет. А здесь уже огромное количество вариантов может быть.

Comment: Чек фискализируется в 1с?

Comment: @kio
"Тогда скорее всего потребуется доработка со стороны 1с, так как готового api скорее всего нет."
 
Ошибаетесь, из коробки у 1С всегда есть автоматический REST-интерфейс (OData). Тут уже только вопрос в том, покроет ли он потребности в данной задачи.

Comment: @Sagittarius Согласен забыл про неё, я его не использовал так как он не подходил по функционалу. Здесь, если задача вызывать при создании чека, она не подойдет. А вот если с заданной регулярностью проверять появление новых чеков, то можно и так.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае надо сначала определиться, кто будет инициировать вызов: 1С отправлять данные, после необходимого события, либо Python всегда вызывает 1С.

1С позволяет обмениваться данными с помощью HTTP-, WEB-сервисов. Для этого придется их создавать в конфигурации, настраивать и публиковать. Если по каким-то причинам нельзя, невозможно и т.п. делать что-то в 1С, тогда можно посмотреть в сторону протокола OData (REST интерфейс, поставляемый платформой "из коробки").

Все примеры и описания есть в книге [Технологии интеграции "1С:Предприятия 8.3"](https://its.1c.ru/db/intgr83#content:3:hdoc)

Comment: А можно ли будет при каждом создании чека создавать excel или любой другой файл с данными по чеку?

Comment: @DaTo, да, конечно. XLS, XML, JSON т.п., все что душе угодно.

Comment: А как это автоматизировать?

Comment: @DaTo, очень расплывчатый вопрос. Пишите код в 1С, который при формировании чека будет формировать файл.